# Multiple statements in angular expression

Tags: angularjs

I'm playing around with Angularjs, and possibly I am abusing it. I am using semicolon to have several statements in an angular expression like this ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z39UF/)):

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4]">
  <td>i = {{ m = k; k = j; j = i + 1; i}}</td>
  <td>j = {{j}}</td>
  <td>k = {{k}}</td>
  <td>m = {{m}}</td>
</tr>
```

At first, I thought that `k` would have the value of `j` before the computation `i+1`, but apparently it does not work like this. The result is:

```
i = 1   j = 2   k = 2   m = 2
i = 2   j = 3   k = 3   m = 3
i = 3   j = 4   k = 4   m = 4
i = 4   j = 5   k = 5   m = 5
```

So apparently assigning `j`to `k` and `k` to `m`, doesn't mean values are copied but that these names are bound together. I can understand that. But something strange happens if I remove the line that display the value of `k` ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pFbc7/)):

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4]">
  <td>i = {{ m = k; k = j; j = i + 1; i}}</td>
  <td>j = {{j}}</td>
  <td>m = {{m}}</td>
</tr>
```

I'm obtaining:

```
i = 1   j = 2   m =
i = 2   j = 3   m =
i = 3   j = 4   m =
i = 4   j = 5   m =
```

That is, `m` does not contain any value, despite the fact that it is bound to `j` (through `k`). It's possible it's because `k` itself is not evaluated.

My question is: isn't it a bug in AngularJS? Surely `k` should be evaluated if it's in the chain of bindings even though it is not displayed directly. Or do I misunderstand something?

I am aware that it is probably not an idiomatic way of using AngularJS, but I want to really understand the expression engine, and I can not explain this behaviour.

Comment: You can narrow this down to behavior in a ng-repeat. Declaring the multiple expressions outside of a repeat has normal/expected behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here that are interacting.

First, your statements are ordered backwards: you're setting k=j before setting j, which leads to its being undefined.

Second, and more importantly, **interpolated expressions (the ones in "{{}}") should not be used change the state of the scope**.  There's a good reason for this:

### Interpolation and Watches

The way interpolation works is that when it compiles your html, angular registers a `scope.$watch` on each interpolated expression.

But these watched expressions can get executed multiple times during a digest: whenever a listener modifies the scope, it causes angular to run through the watches on that scope again.  For this reason, watched expressions really ought to be "idempotent": i.e., they should have no side effects / cause no state changes.  Here it is from the [documentation for `$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch):

> The watchExpression is called on every call to $digest() and should return the value which will be watched. (Since $digest() reruns when it detects changes the watchExpression can execute multiple times per $digest() and should be idempotent.)

### Tracing the Example

Specifically, here's what's going on in your example.  First of all, it has nothing to do with the repeater.  Each `ng-repeat` item gets its own scope, so what's going on here is equivalent to this simpler example:

```
<div ng-app>
    {{ i = 42 }}<br>
    i = {{ m = k; k = j; j = i+1; i }}<br>
    j = {{j}}<br>
    k = {{k}}<br>
    m = {{m}}<br>
</div>
```

(Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abeluga/z39UF/1/))

The digest proceeds like so:

1. Evaluating `{{ i = 42 }}` sets `scope.i` to 42, and displays "42" in the document.  However, since the scope has changed, there's ALSO a "**dirty**" flag set, which means we'll be looping through the watches again (see step 5 below)
2. Evaluating `{{ m = k; k = j; j = i+1; i }}` sets `scope.m` and `scope.k` to `undefined`, and `scope.j` to 43, and displays "42" in the document.
3. Evaluating `{{ j }}` displays "43" in the document.
4. Evaluating `{{ k }}` and then `{{ m }}` both simply display "" in the document, since they're currently undefined.
5. Now, since the dirty flag is set, we repeat all these watches; this time, when we run `{{ m = k; k = j; j = i+1; i }}`, k = j works because j exists; so k is assigned a value of 43.
6. When we get down to `{{ k }}` this time, its value has changed from undefined to 2, so the dirty flag is set once again, but now the document is displaying "k = 2".  However, `{{ m }}` is still undefined.
7. Just like 5-6, we go through the watches again, and this time, `{{ m = k; k = j; j = i+1; i }}` results in m being set to 43.

### Tangent: Double-processing Watches?

Tangentially, an interesting thing I encountered while tracing through the digest code: it seems that the dirty flag is ALWAYS set to true the first time through the watches, because a never-before-checked watch has no recorded "last" value.  Seems like this would result in lots of unnecessary double-processing.  This seems true even when the watched value is a constant like {{2}}.  Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very interesting! I understand now that idempotency is necessary. My original idea was to try to write the Fibonacci numbers using that kind of constructs, but I guess I have to use a controller :)